# A different approach to understanding programming

Tags: python, cad

I am new to programming. I decided to stick with Python after messing around with objective-c. 
I'm beginning to get a grasp on most of the basic concepts, but as an artist, I think visually. This said, I would like to attempt to work in reverse. In other words, I'd like to start out with a complete, functional piece of software and look at the code and mess around with it to see what does what. This is kind of a similar approach to CAD modeling, where you can see which features in the model affect it, and how. This may not make sense to those who are not familiar with CAD, but I hope someone out there can relate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exploring existing projects is an excellent way to learn programming. Breaking existing code and fixing it is an even better way.

There are many open source projects out there that you might want to explore. Some of them are code libraries, while others are entire applications. As you are new to programming, you may want to consider looking at projects that are not too gigantic as it might be overwhelming.

Additionally, it may be even more helpful for you to dissect a program that you would actually use. I have not used this program, but PythonCAD might interest you:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pythoncad/

This most likely does not fall into the small or simple category of open source projects but it sounds like you may already understand the intended functionality which should be of considerable aid to you in your exploration.

Browse through Google Code for open source Python projects that are of interest to you:

http://code.google.com/query/#q=python

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to take a look at the [PyRoom](http://www.pyroom.org) project, a no non-sense text editor for writing without distractions. It's barely 2K lines of code and seems simple to understand. You can access the repository [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~pyroom-dev/pyroom/trunk/files).